# How to get variable totalCredit to increment properly

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

In my program, I am supposed to have the user enter course selections, up to a max of 3. The problem I am running into is that in order for the switch to end at 3 courses, it has to update the value of totalCredit until it reaches 9 (which is a total of 3 courses worth 3 credits each). Basically, when you've already entered 3 courses and you try to enter a 4th, it should spit out case -3 from within the WritePrompt method, but it appears to not be changing the totalCredit variable at all.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleRegisterStudent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            (new Program()).run();
        }


        void run()
        {
            int choice;
            int firstChoice = 0, secondChoice = 0, thirdChoice = 0;
            int totalCredit = 0;
            string yesOrNo = "";

            System.Console.WriteLine("Teacher's Copy");

            do
            {
                WritePrompt();
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (ValidateChoice(choice, firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice, totalCredit))
                {
                    case -1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Your entered selection {0} is not a recognized course.", choice);
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        Console.WriteLine("You have already registerd for this {0} course.", ChoiceToCourse(choice));
                        break;
                    case -3:
                        Console.WriteLine("You can not register for more than 9 credit hours.");
                        break;
                    case -4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Registration Confirmed for course {0}.", ChoiceToCourse(choice));
                        totalCredit += 3;
                        if (firstChoice == 0)
                            firstChoice = choice;
                        else if (secondChoice == 0)
                            secondChoice = choice;
                        else if (thirdChoice == 0)
                            thirdChoice = choice;
                        break;
                }

                WriteCurrentRegistration(firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice);
                Console.Write("\nDo you want to try again? (Y|N)? : ");
                yesOrNo = (Console.ReadLine()).ToUpper();
            } while (yesOrNo == "Y");


            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for registering with us");
        }

        void WritePrompt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select a course for which you want to register by typing the number inside []");
            Console.WriteLine("[1]IT 145\n[2]IT 200\n[3]IT 201\n[4]IT 270\n[5]IT 315\n[6]IT 328\n[7]IT 330");
            Console.Write("Enter your choice : ");
        }

        int ValidateChoice(int choice, int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice, int totalCredit)
        {
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 7)
                return -1;
            else if (choice == firstChoice && choice == secondChoice && choice == thirdChoice)
                return -2;
            else if (totalCredit > 9)
                return -3;

            return -4;
        }


        void WriteCurrentRegistration(int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice)
        {
            if (secondChoice == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("You are currently registered for {0}", ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice));
            else if (thirdChoice == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("You are currently registered for {0}, {1}", ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice), ChoiceToCourse(secondChoice));
            else
                Console.WriteLine("You are currently registered for {0}, {1}, {2}", ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice), ChoiceToCourse(secondChoice), ChoiceToCourse(thirdChoice));
        }

        string ChoiceToCourse(int choice)
        {
            string course = "";
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    course = "IT 145";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    course = "IT 200";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    course = "IT 201";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    course = "IT 270";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    course = "IT 315";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    course = "IT 328";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    course = "IT 330";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return course;
        }
    }
}
```

No error messages, no build errors, it's the just program logic that isn't working.

Comment: *"it appears to not be changing the totalCredit variable"* - How are you observing this?  There is only one line of code which modifies that variable.  When you debug, is that line reached?  After it executes, has the value of the variable changed?  It sounds more like you're making assumptions rather than observing behavior and asking about that behavior.  Step through the code in a debugger.  When you do that, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've successfully entered 3 courses, totalCredit gets incremented by 3 for 3 times. Given its initial value of 0, the value of totalCredit while processing the 4th course entry would be 9

If you want to trigger the -3, you need to change:

```
else if (totalCredit > 9)
```

to:

```
else if (totalCredit >= 9)
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thanks so much.